# Account name in list item not updating

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I have multiple lists that use `Person/Group` fields.

A few people have had their last names changed recently and while their profiles are synced to the AD, the names displayed in the list items are still the old names.  They didn't get new accounts, their last names were just changed in the AD.

**Example**: Employee field in a list says `"Ashley W"` (old), but when you click on it, the profile says `"Ashley H"` (new).

How do I get their names to update in the items?

[image: screenshot]